# what is the meaning of upload image, how can we use that

Tags: cloudinary

I know this might be a very very basic and easy question to ask, but somehow I could not understand the difference between the two.

I googled a lot and read many things but could not find an answer to distinguish the two.

I was reading the FAQ'sof Cloudinary, which states that:

> Cloudinary covers from image upload, storage

So my question is What is image upload vs image storage? Secondly, why do we upload the images?

As a normal user, I understand that upload is transferring files to different systems, but what is the use in cloudinary then?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct upload is transferring files from one system(Local drive, different URL, other storage in a cloud (S3)) to diffrent system, for example Cloudinary storage.

Image storage is the place that the image is and the amount of storage that they take.

So, for example, if I have an image A.jpg on my local drive in my computer. And that image is 100KB. I can upload it to my Cloudinary (Storage in the cloud) and After I upload it to my Cloudinary account I can check my storage and I'll see that I have 100KB in my storage.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary is a cloud-based service, and as such, in order to use their image management solutions such as image manipulation, optimization and delivery, you have to upload your images to the cloud. Images uploaded to Cloudinary are stored in the cloud utilizing Amazon's S3 service.

Cloudinary provides a free tier where you can store up to 75,000 images with a managed storage of 2GB. 7500 monthly transformations and 5GB monthly net viewing bandwidth.

As you said, uploading is transferring a file to a different system. With cloudinary you can upload a local file, upload a file using a remote HTTP(s) URL or upload a file from S3 bucket.

In conclusion, Cloudinary isn't just a cloud storage service, we [upload images](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_upload) to Cloudinary so that we can perform all kinds of image manipulations to images.

For more details you can read this documantation:

http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_upload